# To display the arrays from CSV file to the following format using python

Tags: python, list, csv, tuples

I am trying to print certain data from CSV file to python environment. I got an output in this format after writing this code.

```
X = [('1',), ('2',), ('3',), ('4',), ('5',), ('6',)]
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT in the following Two formats. Each for a different usage**

```
(1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6)

((1,)  ,( 2  , )  , (3  , )  ,  (4  ,) , (5  ,), (6 ,) )
```

But I am interested in displaying the output in some other format as I mentioned. Because in ABAQUS software tool, it takes only those type of formats which I have mentioned. Thank you guys in advance for your time and patience. >

```
filename='x.csv’

with open(filename) as f:

...     data=[tuple(line) for line  in  csv.reader(f)]

...

>>> print data

[('1',), ('2',), ('3',), ('4',), ('5',), ('6',)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
X = [('1',), ('2',), ('3',), ('4',), ('5',), ('6',)]

tuple(int(e) for t in X for e in t)
# (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

tuple(tuple(int(e) for e in t) for t in X)
# ((1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,))
```

**Update:**
To convert, strings of floating point numbers in french numbering system (which uses comma instead of decimal point, set the locale correctly and use `locale.atof`. Make sure the `locale.setlocale(...)` call succeeds and if not you might have to install the `fr_FR` locale on your system

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.utf-8')
'fr_FR.utf-8'
>>> X= [('1,2',), ('2,3',), ('3,4',), ('4,2',), ('5,3',), ('6',)]
>>> tuple(locale.atof(e) for t in X for e in t)
(1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.2, 5.3, 6.0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Kindly let me know to deal when you have decimal values. In france we use comma, to mention a decimal or float number.                                              X= [('1,2',), ('2,3',), ('3,4',), ('4,2',), ('5,3',), ('6',)].                                                         I get Value error : invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,2'

Comment: You can use something like this for a quick answer `tuple(tuple(float(e.replace(',', '.')) for e in t) for t in X)`. But you should consider setting proper LOCALE and using `locale.atof` instead of `float`

Comment: Hi @Sunitha. I tried using your coding to change from **X= [('1,2',), ('2,3',), ('3,4',), ('4,2',), ('5,3',), ('6',)]** to **X= [('1.2',), ('2.3',), ('3.4',), ('4.2',), ('5.3',), ('6.0',)] ** 
 by importing **'locale'** and mentioning this line **(locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'FR'))**.  I am unable to get the desired output as a DOT decimal values(1.2), i can still see the **output as comma decimal separator** output. I tried few other codes but was not successful. Please lend me a hand.

Comment: yes, you are right. I am missing that installation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
X = [('1',), ('2',), ('3',), ('4',), ('5',), ('6',)]

from itertools import chain

res1 = tuple(map(int, chain.from_iterable(X)))
# (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

res2 = tuple((int(t[0]), ) for t in X)
# ((1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,))
```

Alternatively, to derive `res2` from `res1` and avoid repeated integer conversion:

```
res2 = tuple((i,) for i in res1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# for the first output
output = tuple(int(x[0]) for x in X)
# (1, 2, 3)

# for the second output
output_2 = tuple((int(x[0]), ) for x in X)
# ((1, ), (2, ), (3, ))
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, how can i do changes in my code by collaborating with yours? because instead of using PRINT statement twice, a common code will be great from you. Thank you again :)